# Can not save best weights using keras while training process

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, pycharm

I'm new in Keras. I want save  model with best weights like as:

```
model1.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="RMSprop")

model1.summary()

mcp_save = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_accuracy', mode='auto', verbose=2)
callbacks_list = [mcp_save]


epochs = 5000
batch_size = 50

# fit the model
history = model1.fit(x_train, y_train,
                batch_size=batch_size,
                epochs=epochs,
                callbacks=callbacks_list,
                validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                verbose=2)
```

I couldn't come across warning or error message on Pycharm 2019 Community edition. But I am not able to see **'best_model.h5'** on project file folder or somwhere else on my computer after trainig process finished?? Would you give me advices please?? What are my faults??

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me. I use this callback often. All I can suggest is that you use a full path to designate where to save the model rather than a relative path.